# Implementing Async ExecuteNonQuery() for IDBCommand vs SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync

Tags: c#, async-await, ado.net, task-parallel-library

I'm using `IDBCommand` for my database layer in order to switch to other database providers than `SqlDataProvider`.

`SqlCommand` has all Async methods like ExecuteNonQueryAsync but `IDBCommand` does not contains async method.

In future we might need to switch to another data provider other than `Sql`, I just cannot use `SqlCommand` directly.

I'm just thinking to implement my own Async versions. Would there be any performance concern if I implement my own? Or Its better to use microsoft implemented Async methods that are available for `SqlCommand` object?

In the following way, I implemented my `Async` methods. The following is a Synchronous:

```
public int ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType commandType, string commandText)
{
    PrepareCommand(commandType, commandText);
    var noOFRowsAffected = _dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SetParameters(_dbCommand.Parameters);
    return noOFRowsAffected;
 }
```

The following is the `Async` version:

```
public async Task<int> ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CommandType commandType, string commandText)
{
    PrepareCommand(commandType, commandText);

    var noOFRowsAffected = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        return _dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    });

    SetParameters(_dbCommand.Parameters);
    return noOFRowsAffected;
}
```

> Please note that exception handling would be handled by the calling
>   layer.

Can anyone give me the right direction? Is it a correct way to do the async operation or I should use microsoft implemented `SqlCommand` to use its own methods? Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the abstract classes inside the `System.Data.Common` namespace. They do have asynchronous methods. For example:

[`DbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.executenonqueryasync)

The `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` inherits from this base class, and hopefully the other data providers also do so.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed! :)

Answer (score 2):

Beware that, although you can leverage data providers to create your objects, you'll still need to account for differences in the SQL for each provider.

If you really want your code to be agnostic, you're better with Entity Framework, NHibertnate or any other ORM.

You should never use `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `async-await`. Use `Task.Run` instead. But not for async over sync, which is also a bad practice.

If you work with `DbCommand` instead of `IDbCommand` you already have `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell me whats the problem with Task.Factory.StartNew? It internally calls Task.Run with default options. 

Can't we use Task.Run with async await? Task.Run is awaitable task. so whats the problem> It would be great if you can give some light. thanks :)

Comment: `Task.Run`  invokes `Task.Factory.StartNew` but not using the default parameters for `Task.Factory.StartNew`. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper). No reason to write all that boilerplate ADO.NET code and worry about whether you may change providers. It also supports async operations across the board.

> Dapper has no DB specific implementation details, it works across all
>   .NET ADO providers including SQLite, SQL CE, Firebird, Oracle, MySQL,
>   PostgreSQL and SQL Server.

**Tutorial**

https://dapper-tutorial.net/async

Comment: Thanks @William for letting me know about this. Is this open source?

Secondly I don't want to use any wrapper. Performance is a big concern in my case

Comment: The only thing that Dapper offers over plain ADO.NET is mapping to types. Dapper is not DB specific because you have to account for the differences.

Comment: Mapping to types using Reflection right? This is what I want to avoid. Performance is really a big concern.

Comment: Yes it's open source. It extends the IDbConnection. Dapper was developed by the StackExchange team, it's used by this site. Performance is not a concern. Read the section on Performance https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

Comment: Dapper doesn't use reflection but generates new (and caches) wrapped types for mapping, which is significantly faster